# Why does comparing for current month work one way, but Studio complains about the other?

Tags: android, calendar

This snippet of Android code seems fine according to Studio:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
if (currentMonth == Calendar.DECEMBER) {

}
```

But this snippet isn't:

```
if (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER) {

}
```

The error comes back claiming the second term 'Calendar.DECEMBER' must be one of the days of the week statics (e.g. Calendar.SUNDAY, Calendar.MONDAY, etc...)

Comment: From the intent actions menu, it should let you edit the inspection settings of the IDE. Which inspection is it and what setting do you have for it?

Answer (score 0):

This inspection looks at Android API calls that have been annotated with various support annotations (such as RequiresPermission or UiThread) and flags any calls that are not using the API correctly as specified by the annotations.

if you use:

```
if ((int)c.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER) {

    }
```

this error will dismissed.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful.